# removing/overwriting duplicate rows of information

Tags: r, filtering, duplicates

Hi I have a dataset and I'll keep it very basic, although in reality it is much more complex.

```
 mydata= data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), value=c(NA, 5,3,2,NA,NA,NA,9),value2=c(6,6,9,8,8,99,99,99))
```

I have different groups in the first column.  The second column is what is causing me issues.  Occasionally in my data there are duplicate rows, in a sense that an extra row is created for the same value2+group combination by replacing the value1 with an NA.

For example, rows 1 and 2 are the same except for the NA/5.  I consider row 2, with the '5' in the 'value1' column to be the correct row and correct value.

Is there a way for my to filter this dataset to remove duplicates in that duplicates are considered rows where every value matches except the 'value1', **grouped by the 'group' column**.   Also if this could be done in a way that **does NOT involve filtering in someway for NAs - they are just an example and in my real scenario they could be 'XYZ'**

so desired solution is removing:

row 1,
row 4,
row 5,
row 6,

resulting dataset = row 2,3,7

Comment: Based on the dataset, 1, 5, 6, 7 should be removed.

Comment: In your real scenario, perhaps, you need to replace the `is.na(value)` with `value!='XYZ'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
        group_by(group) %>% 
       filter( !((duplicated(value2)|duplicated(value2,
                   fromLast=TRUE)) & is.na(value)))
#    group value value2
# 1     1     5      6
# 2     1     3      9
# 3     2     2      8
# 4     3     9     99
```

Comment: isnt there a way to keep the original rownames in dplyr? surely that would be useful for removing duplicate rows

Comment: @rawr  I think we have to create a new column with rownames.